# Where to put SSL certificates so PHP curl will use them

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I know I can explicitly set a certificate that curl should use, but due to the nature of my application, I dont want to have certificate management in my code.
Instead I would like to add the self-signed certificate to `/etc/ssl/certs` and let curl work.

After digging in goole I found that apparently Curl has its own location for certificates different than the OS `/etc/ssl/certs`, I also found how I can change it to a custom one by recompiling curl, but I cannot find what is the actual default.

Where should I put all the certificates so that curl and all libraries (guzzle, httpful, etc.) will work with them out of the box without any extra configuration.

Comment: Setting `CURLOPT_CAPATH` does not require re-compiling cURL ...

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/485597/default-ca-cert-bundle-location